# D.e which solving with parametrisation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve next d.e which can be solved with parametrization (that classification group).

$$y'^3-4xyy'+8y'^2=0$$

```
DSolve[y'[x]^3 - 4 x*y[x]*y'[x] + 8 y'[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
```

And its stucked in RUNNING.

How I can solve this equation but with using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do I think is to solve for `y'[x]` and solve the ODE for each root if possible.

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode = y'[x]^3 - 4 x*y[x]*y'[x] + 8 y'[x]^2 == 0      
sol = y'[x] /. Solve[ode, y'[x]] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First solution is

```
DSolve[y'[x] == sol[[1]], y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The other 2 roots have no analytical solutions. NO hang. DSolve replies right away

```
DSolve[y'[x] == sol[[2]], y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]